# Retrieve ALL video datas with Youtube API V3 PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am having issues with YouTube Data API. I'm working on a PHP function to retrieve all videos information in JSON format from a YouTube channel, and then put that into a file.

So far I managed to call the API and retrieve the first 50 videos info; am also knowing the method to create the file.

I know that I have to use the `nextPageToken` parameter to loop the function until there is no `nextPageToken`, but I'm stuck. I've seen a lot of similar posts with this problem, but none of them really helped me.

To sum up, I need help to:

- use `nextPageToken` to collect information after 50 videos;
- collect this information each turn of the loop.

So far the code I found and used:

```
function youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token=''){
    $myQuery = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=".$API_key."&channelId=".$channelID."&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=".$max_results;
    $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myQuery);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
            
        curl_close($ch);
            
        $data = json_decode($response);


        if(!empty($data->nextPageToken)){


       return youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $searchResponse['nextPageToken']);
     }

}

youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token='');
```

Thank you for helping (am a humble beginner -_-).

Comment: Be more specific, what goes wrong when you try this code?

Comment: `$searchResponse` is undefined so `$searchResponse['nextPageToken']` will not work. You have `$next_page_token` as an argument for you function, but you never use that variable at all.

Comment: "_collect this information each turn of the loop_" What loop? Your function also doesn't seem to return anything that could be used, you _are_ getting `$data` but not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a friend and he helped me with my issue. This code didn't work because I didn't have the right arguments... and many other problems. This code works to retrieve videos info from a channel and write it in a JSON file

```
    <?php 

$API_key    = 'API_key';
$channelID  = 'channelID';
$max_results = 50;
$table = array();
$file_name = 'all-videos.json';

function youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token,$videos,$file){
    
    $dataquery = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=".$channelID."&maxResults=".$max_results."&order=date&pageToken=".$next_page_token."&key=".$API_key;
    
    $ch = curl_init();
        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dataquery);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
        
    curl_close($ch);
        
    $data = json_decode($response);


    foreach ($data->items as $item){
        array_push($videos,$item);
    }

    $content = json_encode($videos);
    file_put_contents($file, $content);

    if(!empty($data->nextPageToken)){

        youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $data->nextPageToken, $videos, $file);
    } 
}

youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token='', $table, $file_name);
?>
```

Comment: But may I ask why having tail recursion instead of a simple `do ... while` loop?

Comment: Honestly I don't know... I will answer that question when I have more experience ;)

Comment: OK, I'll refactor that function for you below.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: this is not an actual answer to OP's question, but only a code refactoring of his own answer below.)

Here is your code refactored such that to have a `do...while` loop instead of tail recursion:

```
function youtube_search_paginated(
    $API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token, $videos, $file)
{    
    $dataquery = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=".$channelID."&maxResults=".$max_results."&order=date&key=".$API_key;

    if (!empty($next_page_token))
        $dataquery .= "&pageToken=".$next_page_token;
    
    $ch = curl_init();
        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dataquery);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
        
    curl_close($ch);
        
    $data = json_decode($response);

    foreach ($data->items as $item){
        array_push($videos,$item);
    }

    $content = json_encode($videos);
    file_put_contents($file, $content);

    return $data->nextPageToken;
}

function youtube_search(
    $API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $videos, $file)
{
    $next_page_token = NULL;
    do {
        $next_page_token = youtube_search_paginated(
            $API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $next_page_token, $videos, $file);
    } while (!empty($next_page_token));
}

youtube_search($API_key, $channelID, $max_results, $table, $file_name);
```

Comment: Nice ! I understand the do... while... instruction. This seem to be a more logical way to execute the function.
And you added a condition to change the dataquery string if there is a next page token. 
Thank you :)  I think the code you corrected will help lots of people who were stuck in an infinite loop like me